# disabling numbering for Axiom environment

Tags: numbering

I know

`\begin{equation*} \end{equation*}` 
doesn't number my equation, but even though that's true for equations, I am unable to use it for Axioms, where I have included the environment as

`\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}`

and adding `*` after the argument of `\begin{} \end{}` class doesn't remove the numbering, and also `\nonumber` doesn't do it as well.

Can someone please point me out what is simple possible solution of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you use the `amsthm` package to create theorem-like environments, all you need to do is write

```
 \newtheorem*{axiom}{Axiom}
```

in the preamble to turn off numbering for `axiom` environments.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped!

Could you kindly share a complete indented Latex documentation, that might be useful I guess.

Comment: Also one thing:

Is there a possibility that I manually enumerate my axioms, or any other environment so far in the article?